# How to alert ckeditor value on keyup event in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

code:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#question').keyup(function() {
            var value = CKEDITOR.instances['question'].getData();
            alert(value);
        });
    });
</script>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="question" id="question"></textarea>
```

In this code I have created ckeditor which work perfectly but now I want the value on my alert which is not working yet I do't know why ? So, How can I fix this issue? Please help me out this problem.

Thank You

Comment: can anybody help me please ?

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/x7rbfn70/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your js like below:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['question'].on('change', function() { 
  var value = this.getData();
  alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of `keyup` need to use `key`

*JS:*

```
var e =CKEDITOR.instances['question'];
e.on('key',function() {
            var value = e.getData();
            alert(value);
        });
```

*HTML:*

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="question" id="question"></textarea>
```